# Formato de fechas de float a tipo fecha

Tags: date, formato, sql-server-2017

Buen día a todos
Posiblemente este problema suele ser trillado
Estoy obteniendo día en formato float ,mes en formato float y año en formato float los 3 campos por separados
También obtengo hora en float y los minutos en float
Cuál sería la mejor forma de convertir todos estos campos en un campo de fecha sin que sea costoso para el servidor gracias de antemano me servirían muchísimo su gran ayuda

Comment: ¿Que tipo de dato, estas trabajando?, se supone que date por la etiqueta, pero mencionas hora y minuto. ¿Que parte de código tienes?, y como te pregunta @yeissonpinilla ¿cuál es la necesidad? Es que de la pregunta no se deduce, si lo que quieres es obtener, insertar, modificar. Extraer a un cliente.... Edita la pregunta y la modificas exponiendo todo el escenario completo, seguro que se te puede ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

¿cuál es la necesidad de recibir esa información como floats separados en lugar de recibirlo como formato fecha? Me gustaría conocer tu código para ver qué estás haciendo (o tus tablas) pues de lo contrario es muy difícil entender qué estás haciendo.

Comment: No me permite comentar por temas de reputación. No lo repetiré.